# While loop not terminating VBA

Tags: excel, while-loop, vba

This is partial code. Basically I want to run a loop that terminates either when totalHoursNeeded is at 0 or below, or currentDate is at 6/30. The variable totalHoursNeeded is a global variable, and is reduced incrementally in function runReport. During runReport, currentDate, which is also a global variable, is also reassigned.

So lets say currentDate is initialized as 3/1/2016, and totalHoursNeeded is initialized as 234. runReport will be run on the basis of 200 hours, will set current date to be something like 5/5/2016, and  then set totalHoursNeeded to be 34 (200 is the max each report can be run). Then, what I want to do is run another report, but instead of it being 200 and 3/1/2016, I want it to be 34 and 5/5/2016.

The issue is that these reports can't go past 6/30/2016; so for instance if I need to run a report based on 200 hours, and the starting date is 6/23/2016, the ending date needs to be 6/30/2016 and the amount of hours in the report needs to be correspondingly reduced.

Anyway, the while loop below is not terminating

```
Dim currentDate As Date
Dim totalHoursNeeded As Long
Dim totalHoursInExtension As Long
Dim hoursPerDay As Long


 While totalHoursNeeded > 0 Or Not (Month(currentDate) = 6 And Day(currentDate) = 30)

            'make a new word document object
            Dim nWord As New Document

            Set nWord = Documents.Open("c:\document\here", Visible:=False)

            'run and save the report
            On Error GoTo errhandler:

            'if the extensions have not been written through 6/30 of any year
            If Not (Month(currentDate) = 6) And Not (Day(currentDate) = 30) Then
                'run a report based on the current row, two worksheets, and word object
                totalHoursNeeded = totalHoursNeeded - runReport(row, summary, oWorksheet, nWord)
                saveReport row, totalHoursInExtension, oWorksheet, nWord
            Else

            End If
        '   Close things
            nWord.Close False

    Wend
```

Comment: where do you change currentDate?

Comment: in runReport....it's not included in this post.....at this point it shouldn't matter because totalHoursNeeded should also be reduced to 0 and the loop should terminate.

Comment: it should be somewhere between while and wend

Comment: answered it; the problem is the OR statement. The or statement means that either part of the logic need to be true for the conditional to validate as true; I have since switched it to AND, and the while loop terminates fine.